# Request root-permissions in Android cordova App

Tags: java, android, cordova, root

I am using cordova to develop an Android Application. I have written my own plugin for some functionality that i need. E.g. I need a possibility to reboot the Android-Device from the application.

On a rooted Android 4.4-device this code used to work fine:

```
if (action.equals("reboot")) {
  try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
    proc.waitFor();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Could not reboot", ex);
  }
}
```

However on another rooted Android 5.1-device this does not work anymore. I get the following Error-Message.

```
V/MyCompanyC(  745): MyCompanyCustom:reboot
I/MyCompanyC(  745): Could not reboot
I/MyCompanyC(  745): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, reboot] Working Directory: null Environment: null
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at MyCompanyCustom.execute(MyCompanyCustom.java:81)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:133)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkExposedJsApi.exec(XWalkExposedJsApi.java:40)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/MyCompanyC(  745): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
I/MyCompanyC(  745):      ... 12 more
```

The Android 5.1-device is definately rooted. I have full adb-access to everything. But why does the app not get the root-privileges?

Comment: possibly, the other device's root app is configured to deny SU requests by default.

Comment: Thank you! Both devices are rooted from the chinese-manufactorer. However on both devices I am not able to find any "Root-apk" like superSU. What does this mean? Do I need to configure something? If there is no root-app present, how did it work in the first place for the 4.4 device?

Comment: I think that there **is** a root app, but you don't know that it is a root app. To see it - uninstall your app from 4.4 device, and install again. Then run it, and see, which app will show the root request dialog. If there is really no root management app installed, then I think you should install one. You can find how to do it on your specific device on the internet, or using some universal rooters like Kingo Root, etc.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. There was no root app and it was not possible to install one. That was the problem. I fixed it, by installing the app as a system-app. Thank you for your comments!